# Trigonometric series - are there possible Fourier series applications for it?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, trigonometric-series

For a function $f$ with period $P$ the Fourier series is
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{P}\right)+b_n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{P}\right)}$$

I want to modify the function to be

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(\ln{n})x}{P}\right)+b_n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi(\ln{n})x}{P}\right)}$$

Is there a modified application of the properties of Fourier series and/or transform that can be formed for this type of function?

**Edit** I made some edits but my question is still the same.

Comment: If $b_n=i a_n$, then it might be possible to use Euler's Theorem to convert it into some kind of pseudo-harmonic series.

Comment: seems like the argument of the series can be written as a sine of the sums: $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta $

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question @OfekGillon

Comment: Fourier transform gets many of it's properties from the fact that the basis functions are orthogonal to each other which is due to the integral difference of frequency and integer number of periods integrated over ( in case of fourier series ). Of course you can define your basis functions to be as you want them to, but you will have to re-calculate or re-derive the inner product space and any "fast" transform and basically all other theory related to the transform.